# Why can we assume that $K_n\subset \text{int}(K_{n+1})$ where $K_n\subset X$ where $X$ is a locally compact space?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

I am trying to understand the proof of Prokhorov's theorem. In particular, the implication that a tight family is relatively compact for the narrow convergence. We assume that out space is complete, separable, and locally compact.

The author begins by constructing a sequence of $K_n$ of compact sets such that,
$$\mu(X\setminus K_n)\leq \frac{1}{n}$$
for all $n\in \mathbb{N},$ where $K_n\subset X$ for each $n\in \mathbb{N}.$ Then since the space is locally compact we assume that $K_n\subset \text{int}(K_{n+1}).$ I don't understand why we can do this. If $K_n$ is sequence of compact sets then I understand that by writing $K_n'=\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}K_i$ we can construct an increasing sequence of compact sets such that $K_n'\subset K_{n+1}'$ but how does one construct a sequence such that $K_n'\subset \text{int}(K_{n+1})?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so assume that $K_n$ is compact and $\mu(X\setminus K_n)\leq \frac{1}{n}$ for all $n$.

Inductively, define $K_1'=K_1$

For general $n\geq 2$, assume that we've obtained a modification $K_j'$ for $1\leq j<n$ such that, in addition to the above conditions, $K'_{j-1}\subseteq Int(K_j')$ for all $j$.

For each $x\in K'_{n-1}$, pick some relatively compact open neighbourhood $U_x$ of $x$. Then, by compactness there exists $x_1,...,x_M$ such that $K'_{n-1}\subseteq \cup_{m=1}^M U_{x_m}$. Then, redefining $K'_{n}=\overline{\cup_{m=1}^M U_{x_m}}\cup K_n,$ it remains true that $K_n'$ is compact. Furthermore, $K_{n-1}'\subseteq Int(K_n')$ by construction. Finally, $\mu(X\setminus K_n')\leq \mu(X\setminus K_n)\leq \frac{1}{n}$, so this modification has the desired properties.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!